# Setting JDBC connection/socket timeout via persistence.xml

Tags: oracle, jpa, jdbc, timeout

I'm trying to set JDBC timeout via persistence.xml, but it doesn't work.
This is how my persistence.xml looks like:

```html
<persistence-unit name="persistenceUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <jta-data-source>OracleDataSourceExample</jta-data-source>
        <properties>
            <property name="oracle.net.READ_TIMEOUT" value="1"/>
            <property name="oracle.jdbc.ReadTimeout" value="1"/>
            <property name="oracle.net.CONNECT_TIMEOUT" value="1"/>
        </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

So, does anyone have suggestion what to do? (how to set jdbc timeout)

Comment: WHAT "jdbc timeout"? For which operations? persist?, query? JPA queries have a timeout property that can be set.

Comment: I need to set connection/socket timeout, operation is persist

Comment: Most JPA providers allow the use of 3rd party connection pools, such as HikariCP. These connection pools are where you would specify things directly related to JDBC